# Map with geom_bin2d overlay with additional stat info

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I am trying to reproduce something similar to this map using ggplot2: [image: Map]
This is what I've done so far:

---

```
    load("mapdata.Rdata")
    > ls() #2 datasets: "depth" for basemap (geom_contour) and "data" is use to construct geom_bin2d
    [1] "data"  "depth"
    > head(data)
        latitude longitude GRcounts
    740 67.20000 -57.83333        0
    741 67.11667 -57.80000        0
    742 67.10000 -57.93333        1
    743 67.06667 -57.80000        0
    751 67.15000 -58.15000        0
    762 67.18333 -58.15000        0
    ggplot(data=data,aes(x =longitude, y =latitude))
+theme_bw()
+ stat_bin2d(binwidth = c(0.5, 0.5))
+geom_contour(data=depth,aes(lon, lat, z=dn),colour = "black", bins=5)
+ xlim(c(-67,-56)) + ylim(c(65,71))
```

Which gives me this map: [image: My map]

The last step is to display over my geom_bin2d circles with size proportional to the sum of the counts (Grcounts) within each bin.

Any tips on how to do so in ggplot (preferably) would be much appreciated.

---

**follow-up question: alignment mismatch between stat_bin2d and stat_summary2d when using facet_wrap**

When I run the following code on the `diamonds` data set, there are no apparent problem: [image: Diamonds plot by cut] However if I do run the same code on my data, I do get misalignment problems. Any thoughts on what may cause this problem?

```
p<-ggplot(diamonds,aes(x =carat, y =price,colour=cut))+
   stat_summary2d(fun=sum,aes(z=depth,group=cut),bins=10)
p+facet_wrap(~cut)
df <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
summary(df)##now 5 groups, 1 panel
df$x<-with(df,(xmin+xmax)/2)
df$y<-with(df,(ymin+ymax)/2)
plot1<-ggplot(diamonds,aes(carat, price))+ stat_bin2d(bins=10)
plot1+geom_point(data=df,aes(x,y,size=value,group=group),color="red",shape=1)+facet_wrap(~group)
```

This is my Rcode and plot:[image: Mydata plot]

```
p<-ggplot(dat,aes(x =longitude, y =latitude,colour=SizeClass))+
   stat_summary2d(fun=sum,aes(z=GRcounts,group=SizeClass),bins=10)
p+facet_wrap(~SizeClass)
df <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
summary(df)##now 4 groups, 1 panel
df$x<-with(df,(xmin+xmax)/2)
df$y<-with(df,(ymin+ymax)/2)
plot1<-ggplot(dat,aes(longitude, latitude))+ stat_bin2d(bins=10)
plot1+geom_point(data=df,aes(x,y,size=value,group=group),color="red",shape=1)+facet_wrap(~group)

> head(dat[c(7,8,14,21)])###mydata
     latitude longitude GRcounts SizeClass
742  67.10000 -57.93333        1 (100,150)
784  67.21667 -57.95000        1 (100,150)
756  67.11667 -57.80000        1    (<100)
1233 68.80000 -59.55000        2 (100,150)
1266 68.68333 -59.60000        2 (100,150)
1288 68.66667 -59.65000        1 (100,150)
```

My data set can be downloaded here: [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zs23yaq3a8yhe7e/dat.RData)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your dataset doesn't work on my computer will use `diamonds` dataset as example.

Make new plot of your data with `stat_summary2d()` and set `z=` as argument you want to sum (in your case `GRcounts`) and provide `fun=sum` to sum those values. Store it as some object.

```
p<-ggplot(diamonds,aes(carat,price))+stat_summary2d(fun=sum,aes(z=depth))
```

Use function `ggplot_build()` to get data used for plot. Coordinates of rectangles are in columns `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` and sum are in column `value`.

```
df <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
head(df)
     fill         xbin                ybin    value      ymax      ymin yint      xmax      xmin xint PANEL group
1 #55B1F7   [0.2,0.36]           [326,943] 641318.2  942.5667  326.0000    1 0.3603333 0.2000000    1     1     1
2 #1A3955   [0.2,0.36]      (943,1.56e+03]  75585.5 1559.1333  942.5667    2 0.3603333 0.2000000    1     1     1
3 #132B43   [0.2,0.36] (1.56e+03,2.18e+03]    415.8 2175.7000 1559.1333    3 0.3603333 0.2000000    1     1     1
4 #132B43   [0.2,0.36] (2.18e+03,2.79e+03]    304.4 2792.2667 2175.7000    4 0.3603333 0.2000000    1     1     1
5 #244D71 (0.36,0.521]           [326,943] 179486.8  942.5667  326.0000    1 0.5206667 0.3603333    2     1     1
6 #2D5F8A (0.36,0.521]      (943,1.56e+03] 271688.9 1559.1333  942.5667    2 0.5206667 0.3603333    2     1     1
```

For the points calculate x and y positions as mean of `xmin`,`xmax` and `ymin`,`ymax`.

```
df$x<-with(df,(xmin+xmax)/2)
df$y<-with(df,(ymin+ymax)/2)
```

Use this new data frame to add points to your original plot with `stat_bin2d()`.

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(carat,price))+stat_bin2d()+
  geom_point(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y,size=value),color="red",shape=1)
```

[image]

### UPDATE - solution with facetting

To use `facet_wrap()` and combine `stat_bin2d()` and points you should use some workaround as there seems to be some problem.

First, create two plots - one for sums with `stat_summary2d()` and one for counts with `stat_bin2d()`. Both plots should be faceted.

```
plot1 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x =longitude, y =latitude))+
  stat_summary2d(fun=sum,aes(z=GRcounts),bins=10)+facet_wrap(~SizeClass)

plot2 <- ggplot(dat,aes(longitude, latitude))+ stat_bin2d(bins=10)+
    facet_wrap(~SizeClass)
```

Now extract data from both plots using `ggplot_build()` and store them as objects. For the sums data frame (`df1`) calculated x and y coordinates as in example above.

```
df1 <- ggplot_build(plot1)$data[[1]]
df1$x<-with(df,(xmin+xmax)/2)
df1$y<-with(df,(ymin+ymax)/2)

df2<-ggplot_build(plot2)$data[[1]]
```

Now plot your data using those new data frames - `df1` for points and `df2` for rectangles. With `geom_rect()` you will get rectangles which `fill=` depend on count. For faceting use column `PANEL`.

```
ggplot()+geom_rect(data=df2,aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,
                          ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,fill=count))+
  geom_point(data=df1,aes(x=x,y=y,size=value),shape=1,color="red")+
  facet_wrap(~PANEL)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! This is partly my answer, I do not want the circle to represent the count extracted from stat_bin2d, but the sum of data$GRcounts in each of the bins. I need to calculate the sum for each bin and then plot it. I now see how I can get the locations from ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]] but I'm not sure how to calculate the sum of GRcounts in each bins.

Comment: @GodinA Updated my answer to solve the problem with sum of counts

Comment: I expanded my question. Any ideas of what may cause the problem?

Comment: @GodinA Updated my answer with facet_wrap() example.

Comment: would it be possible to have the overall count per panel (blue scale) repeated (same) on each panel rather than just showing where the value>0 (red circle). I tried to remove facet_wrap() in plot 2, but then the pattern only appear on Panel 1 (as expected) and the points are misaligned... copy x4 the plot2 data sets and specify the panel number, might do the trick... but would still have misalignment issues.