# Manually specifying bins with stat_summary2d

Tags: r, ggplot2, binning

I have a large set of data that consists of coordinates (x,y) and a numeric z value that is similar to density. I'm interested in binning the data, performing summary statistics (median, length, etc.) and plotting the binned values as points with the statistics mapped to ggplot aesthetics.

I've tried using stat_summary2d and extracting the results manually (based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22013347/2832911). However, the problem I'm running into is that the bin placements are based on the range of the data, which in my case varies by data set. Thus between two plots the bins are not covering the same area.

My question is how to either manually set bins using stat_summary2d, or at least set them to be consistent regardless of the data.

Here is a basic example which demonstrates the approach and how the bins don't line up:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2)
df1 <- data.frame(x=runif(100, -1,1), y=runif(100, -1,1), z=rnorm(100))
df2 <- data.frame(x=runif(100, -1,1), y=runif(100, -1,1), z=rnorm(100))
g1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x,y))+stat_summary2d(fun=mean, bins=10, aes(z=z))+geom_point()
df1.binned <-
    data.frame(with(ggplot_build(g1)$data[[1]],
                    cbind(x=(xmax+xmin)/2, y=(ymax+ymin)/2, z=value, df=1)))
g2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x,y))+stat_summary2d(fun=mean, bins=10, aes(z=z))+geom_point()
df2.binned <-
    data.frame(with(ggplot_build(g2)$data[[1]],
                    cbind(x=(xmax+xmin)/2, y=(ymax+ymin)/2, z=value, df=2)))
df.binned <- rbind(df1.binned, df2.binned)
ggplot(df.binned, aes(x,y, size=z, color=factor(df)))+geom_point(alpha=.5)
```

Which generates [image: this image]

In reality I will use stat_summary2d several times to get, for instance, the number of points in the bin, and the median and then use `aes(size=bin.length, colour=bin.median)`.

Any tips on how to accomplish this using my proposed approach, or an alternative approach would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually set breaks with `stat_summary2d`. If you want 10 levels from -1 to 1 you can do

```
bb<-seq(-1,1,length.out=10+1)
breaks<-list(x=bb, y=bb)
```

And then use the `breaks` variable when you call your plots

```
g1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x,y))+
    stat_summary2d(fun=mean, breaks=breaks, aes(z=z))+
    geom_point()
```

It's a shame you can't change the `geom` of the `stat_summary2d` to "point" so you could make this in one go, but it doesn't look as though `stat_summary2d` calculate the proper `x` and `y` values for that.

Comment: This worked nicely for me. Somehow I missed that you could directly specify breaks.

Comment: Do you know, how this could be adjusted, if x and y were factor types? I'm getting `Error : all(sapply(breaks, is.numeric)) is not TRUE` with your solution.

Comment: I figured it out: If `x` or `y` are factor variables, but can directly be transformed to numbers (like "1", "2" ...), just use `as.numeric(bb)` instead of `bb`. Otherwise they can be mapped to integer IDs (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13566768/1498405).