# How to create size varying points with stat_summary_2d

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to vary the size of points created with stat_summary_2d, at present they are all the same size which isn't informative. I would normally use geom_point() but because I want the points central to their correct bins it isn't appropriate, they are inconsistent in their placement relative to the bin centres so an offset also doesn't work.

[image: Example figure, I'd like to vary the size of the points based on a n_distinct(event_key)]

The code relevant for creating the points is:

```
  stat_summary_2d(data = filter(ni_eff, fishyear %in% c('2013', '2014', '2015', '2016') & coverage),
                  mapping  = aes(x = start_long, y = start_lat, z=event_key), 
                  binwidth = c(1, 1),
                  geom = 'point',
                  colour = 'red',
                  shape = 1,
                  # size = event_key,
                  fun     = n_distinct) +
```

Stat_summary_2d doesn't like size in the aesthetics, and also doesn't recognise event_key if it is entered to determine size. I think it should be possible but haven't worked out how, so any help would be appreciated.

Ultimately, I want points centred on 1*1 degree lat-long bins that vary in size given a column event_key within the dataframe with their co-ordinates.

Comment: too bad your `stat_summary2d` doesn't reproduce...kinda makes it hard to help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011980/map-with-geom-bin2d-overlay-with-additional-stat-info

Comment: Thanks shayaa that's exactly what i was after

Answer (score 2):

Similar question with an applicable answer:

[Map with geom_bin2d overlay with additional stat info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011980/map-with-geom-bin2d-overlay-with-additional-stat-info)

Applying my code:

```
point_df <- ggplot(filter(ni_eff, fishyear %in% c('2013', '2014', '2015', '2016') & coverage),
     aes(x = start_long, y = start_lat)) +
     stat_summary_2d(aes(z = event_key), binwidth = c(1, 1), fun = length)
df <- ggplot_build(point_df)$data[[1]]
```

And the size varying points are plotted using `geom_point()` and at the correct lat-long bin centres (x, y) generated from `ggplot_build()`

```
geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, size = value),
                   colour = "red", shape = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add the points manually without `stat_summary2d()` and then use `position_nudge` to adjust the position so the dots are centered. For example:

```
df = data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1:10, c = 1:10)
d <- ggplot(df, aes(a, b, z = c))
d + stat_summary_2d() +
  geom_point(aes(x = a, y = b, size = c), 
             position = position_nudge(-.1, -.1))
```

Comment: Haven't tried that approach yet, ill give it a go and report back

Comment: because the points are offset inconsistently it can't be solved with `position_nudge`